# State estimation in HyperSonic Missiles

Tags: estimation, kalman-filters, tracking, state

I'm curious, what would be the correct approach for state estimation for hypersonic Missiles?

Would it be exclusively GPS and IMU? Historically these are what was used, but I have also seen ground stations with radar or broadcast triangulation used to track missile and provide a target tracking feedback loop. Given the speed of the weapons(and the fact they are basically only long range) I'm assuming this isn't how it's implemented.